# Forgerock OpenAM User Consent History

Tags: oauth-2.0, openam

In the Forgerock OpenAM OAuth 2.0 process, is there any way for a user to know what they have consented to in the past?

In my mind, what the user has consented to is associated with the access token. When the access token has timed out there is no way of retrieving it. This means that there is no way of getting the previous history of what the user has given away as it has not been stored anywhere.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The consent attribute decision is stored in the user data store (OpenDJ). You could query the directory for this attribute.